# Is there a specific reason for why the Breslov never adopted a new head Rabbi after the death of Rabbi Nachman?

Tags: rabbis, breslov

I've read that the Breslov haven't had a head Rebbe of the movement since Rebbe Nachman passed away. I was curious if there was a specific reason for why a new leader was never chosen and if there has ever been an attempt to have a new kind of leadership for the Breslov movement?

Like maybe a council of respected Breslov rebbes from each community who convene as a body for the movement?